# maven deploy to GAE

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I was invited to a gae project (i have permission "Can edit" in google's dev console). When I run `mvn appengine:update` it compiles the project succesfully and finally I have:

```
Please enter code:
```

the browser opens with `https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=o1yeVeHvHvKWwAPY5oDABg&gws_rd=cr` location, and I just see the ordinal google's home page, no codes etc. What I am doing wrong?

P.S. I also tried `appcfg.sh --oauth2 update target/projj`
the same result and I tried to delete $HOME/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java before the laucnh but has no difference either, one thing is that it is created with the following content each time: `{"credentials":{}}`

I am using Fedora 19 x86_64.

UPDATE #1:
I have `Apache Maven 3.3.3` (latest according to maven official download site)
I also tried to use different default browsers (chrome) and turned on all popups, but no result.

May be I need "Is owner" permissions to make uploads? But It seems to be strange. Any ideas?

UPDATE #2:
Now I have "Is owner" permission - and the same result...

UPDATE #4 
I set up Windows 7 on VBox and it works there, btw there is something wrong I think with get parameters, they are added to get string only partly I think that is the problem.

Comment: did you try to use this 'o1yeVeHvHvKWwAPY5oDABg' as the code?

Comment: yes, then I have `Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid_grant`

Comment: and nothing appears on the console?